# Windowsでのファイルパス長の制限でnpmのパッケージが使えない

Tags: windows, npm

Windowsのファイルパス長は最大260文字だと思うのですが、npmのモジュールを使っているとすぐにその制限を超えてしまいます。

今はVirtualBoxでUbuntuを入れて開発してますが、Windowsで直に行きたいのです。

根本的な解決策がありましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

未解決ですが[英語版にも記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155135/node-npm-windows-file-paths-are-too-long-to-install-packages)があるようです。「根本的な解決方法」は提示されていませんが

- 全ての依存パッケージを`package.json`に記述する
- `npm dedupe`で重複したパッケージ階層を解いてあげる
- `npm-flatten`というパッケージを使う

という案が出ています。

`npm-flatten`はメンテされているとは言いがたい状況ですので、上の2つのどちらかが良いのではないでしょうか。

---

`npm dedupe`について補足ですが

```
a
+-- b <-- depends on c@1.0.x
| `-- c@1.0.3
`-- d <-- depends on c@~1.0.9
`-- c@1.0.10
```

といった構造を`npm dedupe`と実行することで

```
a
+-- b
+-- d
`-- c@1.0.10
```

という構造に変更してくれる機能です。
以前は`npm`に登録されていないパッケージ(GHEなど)で上手く動作しない[問題](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4213#issuecomment-33769760)がありましたが、現在は解決しているようです。